# Couldn't insert values in BinaryTree

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

```
class bTree {
    public class Node {
        Node left;
        Node right;
        int val;

        Node () {}
        Node (int val){
            this.val=val;
        }
    }

    Node root;

    public void insert(int val){
        if (root == null){
            root = new Node(val);
        } else {
            Node current = root;
            // If val less than parent node's val go left
            if (val <= root.val){
                if (root.left == null){
                    root.left = new Node(val);
                } else {
                    insert(val);
                }
            }
            // If val greater than parent node's val go right
            else {
                if (root.right == null){
                    root.right = new Node(val);
                } else {
                    insert(val);
                }
            }              // inner else ends
          }           // outer else ends
    }     // insert() ends

    public void displayTree(Node root){
   
        if (root.left != null){
            displayTree(root.left);
        }
        System.out.print(root.val + " - "); 
        if (root.right != null){
            displayTree(root.right);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        bTree bt = new bTree();
        bt.insert(10);
        bt.insert(30);
        bt.insert(4);
        bt.insert(5);
        bt.displayTree(bt.root);
    }
}
```

I was trying to implement a binary search tree and came across a problem inserting values in it. I have implemented it before making a Node main class but now nesting a Node class inside of a main class (like a LinkedList) is complicating it.

```
    public void insert(int val){
        if (root == null){
            root = new Node(val);
        } else {
            Node current = root;
```

Here in this bit `current` is always getting value of `root` which causes not more than 3 items to be inserted. I am aware of this problem but couldn't get around it. Any redesign in the code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could pass the root of a subtree as an argument to your `insert` function.

Comment: @Janez Kuhar @Abra passing a reference of `root` to the `insert()` did work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are not passing the reference of `Node` in `insert()` method to trace down at which node position you are in the current tree.

Currently you are able to insert only 3 items because for 3 items no recursion of `insert(val)` is getting used, but after 3 items you are using recursion of `insert` call and since in that you are not passing current node position this issue is coming.

Here is the working example of insertion in binary tree :

```
class bTree {
    Node root;
    public class Node {
        Node left;
        Node right;
        int val;

        Node () {}
        Node (int val){
            this.val=val;
        }
    }

    public void insert(Node currnode, int val){
        if(currnode == null) {
            root = new Node(val);
            return;
        } 
        if(val <= currnode.val) {
            if(currnode.left == null) {
                currnode.left = new Node(val);
            } else {
                insert(currnode.left, val);
            }
            
        } else {
            if(currnode.right == null) {
                currnode.right = new Node(val);
            } else {
                insert(currnode.right, val);
            }
        }
    }

    public void displayTree(Node root){
   
        if (root.left != null){
            displayTree(root.left);
        }
        System.out.print(root.val + " - "); 
        if (root.right != null){
            displayTree(root.right);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        bTree bt = new bTree();
        bt.insert(bt.root,10);
        bt.insert(bt.root,30);
        bt.insert(bt.root,4);
        bt.insert(bt.root,5);
        bt.displayTree(bt.root);
    }
}
```

Comment: passing the `root` to `insert()` worked! This also helped for my other queries related to OOP. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to know it was helpful to you